# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, true); cookie name

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

What is this cookie called when it gets set? Can I see it in my cookie folder for my browser?

I think it doesn't get set so my login verification fails.

Answer (score 1):

> What is this cookie called when it gets set?

The default name for the cookie is `.ASPXAUTH`. It's [configurable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) through the web.config to have any name.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".SomeName" loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

So check there for anything non-standard.

> Can I see it in my cookie folder for my browser?

You should be able to see it using any browser tools.

Comment: Only if you use a persistent cookie, which the author seems to be since they're passing true.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you create Authentication Cookie yourself, you will need to create **Principal** object and save it inside **Current Thread** in **AuthenticateRequest** event for every request.

Otherwise, when you check **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated**, it will return false.

### Global.asax.cs

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie decryptedCookie =
            Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =
            FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(decryptedCookie.Value);

        var identity = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
    }
}
```

### web.config

Make sure you have authentication tag in web.config. For example,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

### Usage

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var username = User.Identity.Name;
    return View();
}
```

### Browser Plugin

I use [EditThisCookie](http://www.editthiscookie.com/) Chrome Plugin.

[image]

Comment: it's still in web forms (old code from client) but looking into stuff more now