# Avoid manual setting of FormsAuthentication cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I have been have bad behavior at different times using this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, true);
```

How does/will .Net set the cookie otherwise?

I have tried this: ([System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated fails sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753245/665557))

But my User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false

What gives?

Comment: The reason why SetAuthCookie does not work is because you do not  have forms authetocation enabled in web config. Include follwoing setting in your web config within system.web tags: `<authentication mode= "Forms" />`

Comment: i always had it and it mostly worked

Comment: Remember that you can also set the cookie by simply calling `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` method, which will set the authentication ticket/cookie as well as redirect the use to requested URL or default URL.

Comment: Yeah i did that. So that doesn't set the cookie manually and sets it by itself then?

Comment: Yes, that method encapsulates cookie creation functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that forms authentication is enabled in your web config file.

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

Use code like below to make it work. The method `RedirectFromLoginPage` will create the authentication cookie as well as redirect the user to the original page or the default URL i.e. home page.

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))//or whatever method you use
 {
    // Log the user into the site
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, false);
 }
```